# Need to reset terminal after each `sbt` run when using `resolvers += sonatypeRepo`?

Tags: scala, terminal, sbt

I can compile and run from `sbt` with a `build.sbt` file, e.g.,

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

But once I add a Sonatype repo, e.g.,

```
resolvers += sonatypeRepo("releases")
```

the terminal is not properly reset and stops to echo input. I need to call `reset` after each call to `sbt` - any ideas what's causing this? I've already tried deleting `~/.ivy2`, `~/.sbt`, `project` and `target` - to no avail. I'm using `sbt` version `1.0.0`, but it also happens with `0.13.x` versions.

**EDIT:** Just found out that version `0.13.9` does not exhibit this behavior, so this seems to be a `sbt` regression.

Comment: this line makes no sense: `resolvers += sonatypeRepo("releases"` where is the missing `)` ?

Comment: true, added missing `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been reported and being tracked in a couple of places as https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3453 and
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3482

In lieu of an official patch/hotfix from SBT you can exercise one of these workarounds for now

1. stty echo (terminal/bash/shell)
2. reset (terminal/bash/shell)
3. use latest sbt-extras